# access redshift which is in vpc(Account A) from lambda which in another vpc (account B)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Account-B:
contains RDS in vpc(vpc-B) with 4 security groups.
i created assume role for  Account A 
with follwoing Policies :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

In Account-A:

i created lambda function to get connection with redshift (i tested this code from lambda in same account and vpc also then i worked fine i..e nothing wrong in coding part )  in acccount-A (in vpc-A) and this lambda function kept in 2 private subnets and attched igw to vpc and route tables with igw-ip and nat-gateway-ip mapping had done properly.(mostly vpc peering part is perfect (including Security  groups inbound and outbound rules also)

this function attched with role :

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

here on testing lambda function in account-A giving following 
error:time out error

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: You've attached pictures with account numbers, can you remove the account numbers please :)

Comment: Can you confirm the following? The peering connection has been added to all route tables correctly, and the security group on the redshift cluster

Comment: yes ( yaa i added  ips of subnets and vpc ip of lambda ( in account A) to every  security groups of redshift cluster in account-B  and in account -A security group allow all trrafic (inbound and out bound allowing all traffic )

Comment: Have you added the peering connection to your route tables in both VPCs?

Comment: yes i added peering id and cidr of one vpc into another vpc main route table (vice versa)

Comment: i think i am missing some thing with assumed role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215533/discussion-between-maldanna-gk-and-mokugo-devops).

Comment: This chat was very helpful, thanks both. One question is, if the Redshift cluster is publicly accessible, is VPC peering necessary at all? Or do you just need to add the inbound rule for the for the Lambda?

Comment: To answer my own question: When the Redshift cluster is publicly accessible, VPC peering is NOT needed, you just need to deploy your Lambda with a VPC, find the elastic IPs of that VPC, and add inbound rules to your Redshift cluster to allow All Traffic from that IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the result of the Redshift cluster in question being in a public subnet with publicly accessible set to true.

To resolve the Lambda function connecting to the Redshift cluster, the Redshift security group added an inbound rule allowing the elastic IP address of the NAT Gateways for the Lambda subnets to be able to connect.

As an improvement suggestion the Redshift cluster could be moved into a private subnet, with the connection occuring other the peering connection that was setup.

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)